# SQL Help: 3 Tables into 1 Line

Tags: sql

I have three (3) tables that are able to be linked: Sales Orders, Line Items and Products

I want to create a query that shows for each sales order the relevant product types based on it's line items. Every sales order will contain a sensor model and tablet model that are embedded into the Product table (which is linked to the line items table). I have this, but know its wrong:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         "Sales Orders"."id" as "SOID",
         "Product Category" = if("Products"."SubType2"  like '%Sensors%', "Products"."Product Category", ''),
         "Sensor" = if("Products"."SubType2"  like '%Sensors%', "Products"."SubType3", ''),
         "Tablet" = if("Products"."SubType2"  like '%Tablets%', "Products"."SubType3", '')
FROM  "Sales Orders"
LEFT JOIN "Ordered Items" ON "Sales Orders"."id"  = "Ordered Items"."Parent ID" 
INNER JOIN "Products" ON "Ordered Items"."Product Name"  = "Products"."id"  
GROUP BY "SOID",
     "Product Category",
     "Sensor",
     "Tablet"
```

It doesn't error out, but show multiple rows for the sales order with the relevant sensor and tablet, but not in the same row.

it produces:

{2532096000123156204, Positioning,  RTS873, }
{2532096000123156204,,,T100}

What I want is:

{2532096000123156204, Positioning,  RTS873, T100 }

Comment: Sample data, actual output, and desired output would be helpful. Also, please tag your question with the actual RDBMS that you're using. [Why Should I Tag My RDBMS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to S/O.  Few quick items.  Showing sample data helps even if you edit your existing question and paste text in directly and use spaces for alignment and block quote it with the { } icon above editing area.

Readability of SQL can be improved by using "alias" references, especially when using tables and/or columns named with embedded spaces (not cool for long-term maintenance, IMO).  So, where you had "Sales Order", I put "so" as the alias to the table, so the rest of the query can use that as shorthand vs retyping the long name over and over.  Similarly with "Ordered Items" having alias "oi".  So, the only time you should really need to use the double-quotes is with cases of embedded spaces in table/columns.

Now, on to your query.  You did Distinct which is close, but what I think you really need is what I provided.  By doing a group by the sales order ID, it would only return one ID.  Since you have multiple possible line items, I applied a MAX() aggregate.  So, when it is on the first line item that is a Sensor, only then will it get the SubType2 from products table, any other time, defaults to empty string, so the MAX() will only return a value IF it is found.  Similarly for all 3 Product Category, Sensor and Tablet columns.

```
SELECT 
        so.id SOID,
        so.Subject,
        MAX( CASE when p.SubType2 like '%Sensors%'
            then p."Product Category" else '' end ) "Product Category",
        MAX( case when p.SubType2 like '%Sensors%'
            then p.SubType3 else '' end ) "Sensor",
        MAX( case when p.SubType2 like '%Tablets%'
            then p.SubType3 else '' end ) "Tablet"
    FROM
        "Sales Orders" so
            LEFT JOIN "Ordered Items" oi
                ON so.id  = oi."Parent ID"
                INNER JOIN Products p
                    ON oi."Product Name"  = p.id
    GROUP BY 
        so.id,
        so.Subject
```

FEEDBACK.

Yes, look into COALESCE( yourTable.Software1, yourTable.Software2 ).  If the first field is null, the second would take over.. but if you ever have TWO software entries, one could supersede the other based on spelling max.  You could also do similar to the others looking for

```
max( COALESCE( Software1, '' )) Software1,
max( COALESCE( Software2, '' )) Software2
```

So, if a value is null, it returns empty string, but as soon as one IS found it is accepted.  But if you dealing with the same column in a given ordered items table called "Software", and want both, such as

MySoftware1, MySoftware2, AndSoftware3

then that would be slightly different and would be dependent on which specific sql you have... SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Comment: Thank You! I owe you a beer

Comment: This was EXTREMELY helpful. I have added some relevant fields based on your recommendation and it is working as intended. It did expand my request and wonder if this is possible:

I have added a column "Software". it works as you provided, but a sales order could potentially have multiple software line items (up to 4). Is it possible to place response in software2 if software1 is not null?

Comment: @RyanFisher, see revised feedback in answer.